# Running both Chrome and IE 11 Protractor tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

Running `Protractor E2E` tests against both `Chrome` and `IE` is difficult.

I can run them separately, however I need to start/stop the respective Chrome/IE webdriver server before running each tests.

In my `conf.js` file, I export the config options like this :

```js
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: [             
         'spec/my-spec.js',
    ],    

    directConnect: false,    // false when targeting IE, and selen addr is used

    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            browserName: 'chrome'
        }
        ,
        {
            browserName: 'internet explorer',
            'version': '11'
        }
    ]
  }
```

For the standard Chrome tests, I can kick off the Webdriver server:

```
 > webdriver-manager start
```

But for IE, I discovered a way to run Webdriver IE as follows (yeah, pretty ugly):

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Projects\GSDashboard-E2ETests\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1.exe -jar C:\Projects\GSDashboard-E2ETests\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

Then I just launch the Protractor tests:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js
```

I'm searching around for a cleaner and smoother way of running both IE/Chrome e2e tests in one shot.

Is there a solution to this ?

Any advice/guidance is appreciated....

****** **UPDATE** ******

As per answer below, trying to use `seleniumArgs` as follows (where I can specify the `jar` file OR the `IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1.exe` file :

```js
exports.config = {
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',  // comment out
    seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Projects\Dashb-E2ETests\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1.exe'],
    allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
    specs: [
         'spec/MY-spec.js',
    ],    

    directConnect: false,    // false when targeting IE, and selen addr is used
    multiCapabilities: [
        //{
        //    browserName: 'chrome',                        
       ,
        {
            browserName: 'internet explorer',
            'version': '11'
        }
    ]    
}
```

BUT running the test throws this error in a windows cmd prompt:

```
E/launcher - The path to the driver executable must be set by the web   driver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorer‌​Driver.
```

So, I still haven't figured out how to run both IE and Chrome tests (sequentially).

regards,
Bob

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the solution was running this:

> webdriver-manager update --ie

After that, both IE11 and Chrome instances run simultaneously with:

```js
multiCapabilities: [
  {
      browserName: 'chrome'
  }  
  ,
  {
      browserName: 'internet explorer',
      'version': '11'
  }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

include `seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=pathtoIEdriver/IEDriverServer.exe']` property in the conf.js and remove `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'`.If no seleniumAddress is mentioned ,then protractor will automatically start selenium server. So following will be your conf.js for running your protractor test against chrome and ie.

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe'],
  specs: [             
       'spec/my-spec.js',
  ],    

  directConnect: false,    // false when targeting IE, and selen addr is used

  multiCapabilities: [
      {
          browserName: 'chrome'
      }  
      ,
      {
          browserName: 'internet explorer',
          'version': '11'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You need to specify the correct path where you placed the IEDriverServer.exe file in seleniumArgs.

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the path to ` IEDriverServer.exe ` is indeed correct. I have manually copied and pasted the full path into windows explorer.

Comment: So what error are you getting even if you mentioned correct path for IEDriverServer.exe

Comment: Different error indeed. `[10:12:38] E/launcher - The path to the driver executable must be set by the web
driver.ie.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html`

Comment: Please see my **** UPDATE **** section in original post.